# Silabs efm8bb3 is very slow on smbus/i2c master transfers

Tags: performance, delay, i2c, 8051, smbus

While working with Simplicity Studio and Silabs EFM8BB3 (8051 based SoC), I'm observing a very slow transfer rate with a huge pause (up-to 60 ms) in between each byte transfer, as well as (up-to 160 ms) between complete messages on i2c protocol over smbus master interface.

Why is the transfer rate so slow, and is there anything I can do to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

the problem being resolved by activating another timer responsible only for SCL delay/timeout recognition (beware, it's not so clear explained in the datasheet). on **Silabs EFM8BB3** chipset the **timer T2** has a role to provide i2c data stream transfer modulation. the **timer T3** has a role to provide **i2c SCL** timeout handling. to be able to decrease pause in between bytes, T3 has to be enabled. T3 must be configured in `two timers, 8-bit auto reload` mode with low byte interrupt enabled. T3 low byte overflow frequency has to be set to `50000 (reload value is 215)` in case of **400KHz** i2c transfer rate. simplified interrupt handler (just to drop the interrupt flag) has to be implemented. T3 high byte overflow frequency could be set to the lowest available `8000 (reload value is 1)`. the SMBUS interface entity require `Enable SMBus SCL Timeout Detection` activated.

Comment: beware, SILABS released "2017 Christmas present" bug loosing proper Timer3 SYSCLK config and forcing EXTCLK instead. use following post-init config to reverse Timer3 into use of the internal CLK. `SFRPAGE = 0x00;
 CKCON0 = CKCON0_SCA__SYSCLK_DIV_12 | CKCON0_T0M__PRESCALE
   | CKCON0_T2MH__SYSCLK | CKCON0_T2ML__SYSCLK
   | CKCON0_T3MH__EXTERNAL_CLOCK | CKCON0_T3ML__SYSCLK
   | CKCON0_T1M__SYSCLK;`